# First time to Europe, can I transfer in Germany to Copenhagen with a Denmark type D visa?

Tags: visas, transit, germany, denmark, long-stay-visas

Recently I booked the ticket to Copenhagen from China with Air Berlin which means I have to transfer inside Germany. However, I only got the Type D visa valid for Denmark. Will I have troubles transferring with this visa? (not valid for Schengen countries, only for Denmark)

Comment: Transferring or traveling?

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Comment: @MarkMayo Presumably PRC.

Comment: @jpatokal presumably, but the 'obvious' has been wrong before :/

Comment: Why is the citizenship relevant? If he needs a visa for Denmark, he would also need a full Schengen visa for Germany to transfer or transit from an extra- to an intra-schengen flight independent of his citizenship.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Not necessarily, that's only true if the OP needs a visa for short-stays but the question mentions a type D visa. But obviously details on that visa are more relevant.

Comment: @Relaxed: You are right about that.

Answer (score 2):

[This official page](https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/visa/schengen/residence_permit_schengen.htm) states:

> All residence permits issued by the Danish immigration authorities in the form of a residence sticker, or a residence card, which is valid for Denmark, is also valid for entering and staying in other Schengen countries.

Based on that it seems unlikely that you're right that your visa is valid only for Denmark. What exactly makes you conclude that?

Comment: Best to clarify in comments before answering, if something is uncertain.

Comment: A type D visa in the uniform format usually has “Name of the country” under the “valid for” rubric. A type C (short-stay) visa would have “Schengen states” (or a translation) in the same spot. Maybe that's the source of the confusion?

Answer (score 0):

Is your D visa *really* restricted to Denmark? That would be rather unusual.

If it actually is, you will need another Schengen visa valid for Germany to transfer to an intra-schengen flight in Germany.

Comment: Best to clarify in comments before answering, if something is uncertain.  And to provide a link for visa requirements when answering, if possible.